# Too many requests when parsing feeds

Tags: support, api, feed, error-message

I'm trying to create an EPUB from all StackExchange RSS feeds (to use as a "podcast" to read on an offline ebook reader). This involves parsing the recent questions from all SE sites, which quickly leads to a "Too Many Requests from this IP" error.

This is what the script (a Calibre recipe) does:

```python
from calibre.web.feeds.recipes import BasicNewsRecipe
import feedparser

def get_feeds(url):
        feed = feedparser.parse(url)
        entries = []
        entries.extend( feed["items"] )
        sorted_entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda entry: entry["title"])
        feeds = []
        for entry in sorted_entries:
                feeds.append( "%s/feeds" % entry["id"] )
        return feeds

class StackExchange(BasicNewsRecipe):
        title                 = u'StackExchange recent questions'
        oldest_article        = 10
        auto_cleanup          = True
        language              = 'en'
        __author__            = 'Raphaël Pinson'
        max_articles_per_feed = 100
        cover_url = u'http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000011139586-8ft0oi-crop.jpg?04ad178'
        all_feeds = u'http://stackexchange.com/feeds/sites'
        feeds = get_feeds(all_feeds)

        def print_version(self, url):
                return url + '&template=printart'
```

What is the proper way of handling this (maybe using the API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple questions in here.

The answer to the obvious one, "How do I stop getting a "Too Many Requests from this IP" error?" is... make fewer requests.  Stack Overflow is better suited than Meta.SO for information about throttling Calibre scripts.  At least for the API, the limit is [30+ requests in <= 5 seconds](https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits) and [10k requests/day](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), so that's not a bad guess for a ballpark on the limit you're hitting, but it sounds like you might just be able to use trial and error to determine the limit.

As for the API route, some kind soul might stop by and hand you a Stack App that does what they think you want, but you'll probably have better luck [giving it a go yourself](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and posting on [StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/) if you run into problems.  I'm sure that they'd also be eager to share in the fruits of your labor, so it'd be a nicety to offer it to everyone there.

Comment: Thanks. I just found out there is a `delay` parameter to add to Calibre recipes. I will definitely post to StackApps once I get something that works (it's always been my intention :))